# Why do I get an error about one dependency when I try to install another one?

Tags: reactjs, dependencies

When I try to install @types/react and @types/react-dom I get an error about conflicting in dependencies. What does this error mean? What's wrong with my react-persian-datepicker package? I think the problem comes from that dependency. ( Since it's the last dependency I installed before this one)

```
P:\My React Projects\test-project>npm install -D @types/react @types/react-dom
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: react-persian-datepicker@3.0.2
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^18.2.0" from react-dom@18.2.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-dom
npm ERR!     peer react-dom@">=16.8" from react-router-dom@6.21.1
npm ERR!     node_modules/react-router-dom
npm ERR!       react-router-dom@"^6.21.1" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer react-dom@"^18.0.0" from @testing-library/react@13.4.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/@testing-library/react
npm ERR!       @testing-library/react@"^13.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!     1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.8" from react-router@6.21.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-router
npm ERR!     react-router@"6.21.1" from react-router-dom@6.21.1
npm ERR!     node_modules/react-router-dom
npm ERR!       react-router-dom@"^6.21.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   4 more (react-scripts, react-router-dom, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^15.2.1" from react-persian-datepicker@3.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react-persian-datepicker
npm ERR!   react-persian-datepicker@"^3.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@15.7.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^15.2.1" from react-persian-datepicker@3.0.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-persian-datepicker
npm ERR!     react-persian-datepicker@"^3.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Answer (score 1):

Your persian-datepicker only works at react@^15.2.1 and older versions.
You're running react18, hence the conflict.

Check if the persian-datepicker can be updated to a newer version that can run on react18.

Comment: But my datepicker is working now in my project. And I still don't understand why I can't install another dependency because of that.

Comment: Not sure, if there is something in your node_modules or something that's causing this. 
Hard for me to help you any further, but that's what i could get out of your code

Comment: Thanks anyway. I fixed it by installing another datepicker